# For angular google maps I want my scope function to call once the polygon drawing is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

For angular google maps I want my scope function to call once the polygon drawing is done.

Once the polygon is drawn I need my directive scope function called scope.polygonDrawn() to be called and it to know the points drawn?

I'm using angular version 1 with javascript and html.
The current code below is in a directive and works for basic map and for drawing the polygon, but I can get the polygon data points sent to my method.

**This is my current code:**

```
 <ui-gmap-google-map center="config.map.center" zoom="config.map.zoom" options="config.map.options" events="config.map.events" draggable="true">

        <ui-gmap-polygon path="compatiblePolygon" stroke="polygonConfig.stroke" fill="polygonConfig.fill" fit="true" static="true" visible="polygonConfig.visible" editable="polygonConfig.editable" draggable="polygonConfig.draggable" clickable="true" events="polygonConfig.events">
        </ui-gmap-polygon>

        <ui-gmap-markers models="compatiblePoints" coords="'self'" idKey="'id'"
            options="pointsConfig.options"
            clickable="true">
        </ui-gmap-markers>


        //This is my code I need help with:
        <ui-gmap-drawing-manager options="config.drawing.options" static="true" control="drawingManagerControl" events="config.map.events">
        </ui-gmap-drawing-manager>

 </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

This is my js for the cofig:

```
              scope.config = {
                  "map": {
                      "zoom": 12,
                      "pan": true,
                      "center": {
                          "latitude": 51.5200,
                          "longitude": -0.220
                      },
                      "options": {
                          "scrollwheel": false,
                          "streetViewControl": false,
                          "tilt": 45,
                          "zoomControl": true
                      },
                      "events": {
                          "click": scope.editPolygonStop
                      }
                  }
                };

                //I want this to be clicked below when polygon drawn
                scope.editPolygonStop = function(){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below explains how to enable a drawing manager on map, register functions to be called on different events, and how to get polygon path info.
First you need to properly configure drawing manager options as follows

```
self.drawingManagerOptions = {
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [                           
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
            ]
        },
        markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
        },
        polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
        },
        rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
        circleOptions: polyOptions,
        polygonOptions: polyOptions
    };

    self.drawingManagerControl = {};
```

Then you can register event handlers for "overlaycomplete" (called when any kind of overlay is drawn), whereas "polylinecomplete" and "polygoncomplete" are called only on drawing of polyline and polygon:

```
    self.eventHandler = {
        overlaycomplete: function (dm, name, scope, objs) {

            if (dm.drawingMode !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {

                /* Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
                 * mouses down on it. */
                var newShape = objs[0].overlay;
                newShape.type = objs[0].type;

                google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function () {
                    /*Any action to be taken, when shape is clicked*/
                });

            }
        },
        polylinecomplete: function (dm, name, scope, objs) {
            var polyline = objs[0];
            var path = polyline.getPath();

            updateShape (polyline);

            google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', updateShape (polyline));

            google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'remove_at', updateShape (polyline));

            google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', updateShape (polyline));

            google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'dragend', updateShape (polyline));


        },
        polygoncomplete: function (dm, name, scope, objs) {
            var polygon = objs[0];


            updateShape(polygon);

            polygon.getPaths().forEach(function (path, index) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', updateShape (polygon));

                google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'remove_at', updateShape (polygon));

                google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', updateShape (polygon));

            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'dragend', updateShape (polygon));

        }
    };
```

This function gets the polygon path in the form of encoded string, which can be stored in DB. This is called each time a shape is drawn, or edited (insert_at, remove_at, set_at) or dragged (dragend).I am not fully sure how you want to process the polygon data points

```
function updateShape(polygon)
    {
        //This variable gets all bounds of polygon.
        var path = polygon.getPath();

        var encodeString =             
        google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);

        /* Other actions with the polygon data points */
    }
```

Then, in HTML user Gmap drawing manager like this:

```
<ui-gmap-drawing-manager options="drawingCtrl.drawingManagerOptions"  control="drawingCtrl.drawingManagerControl" events="drawingCtrl.eventHandler"></ui-gmap-drawing-manager>
```

This is how to get and save coordinates of polygon in an array:

```
/* This function save latitude and longitude to the polygons[] variable after we call it. */
    function save_coordinates_to_array(polygon)
    {
        /* This variable gets all the coordinates of polygone and saves them. 
         * Finally you should use this array because it contains all latitude 
         * and longitude coordinates of polygon. */
        var coordinates = [];

        /* This variable saves polygon. */
        var polygons = [];

        //Save polygon to 'polygons[]' array to get its coordinate.
        polygons.push(polygon);

        //This variable gets all bounds of polygon.
        var polygonBounds = polygon.getPath();

        for (var i = 0; i < polygonBounds.length; i++)
        {
            coordinates.push({lat: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), lng: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()});
            coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()));
        }

        return coordinates;
    }
```

Comment: I've managed to get it hitting my directive function on complete of polygon drawing now. I pass 3 objects into the function and the first object has lots of data. I'm trying to find the array of points that I just marked

Comment: Do you mean, you need to get coordinates of the polygon? I have edited my question and added a function that does just that. Please let me know if still there is anything else, and accept if you find this help!

Comment: I've made your changes and i've console log the object called path and polyline. I've opened those two objects and cant find the polygon points drawn. Where are they in those objects?

Comment: I get error: "Cannot find name 'google'." for the method above called "save_coordinates_to_array"

Comment: Go it working! No I have an array of objects with lat and lngs

Comment: How would I draw this array of coordinates on the map

Comment: Should I make another question?

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! Yeah sure, make another question, and I will answer how to redraw a polygon on map.

Comment: This is my new question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406895/for-angular-google-maps-i-want-it-possible-for-only-a-polyline-to-be-drawn-from